# PHP: HYPERPAY payment gateway options (Adding one more else if)

Tags: php, if-statement

The website currently have 2 payment options (Mada, Visa/Master). I want to add ApplePay option.

The code is using [ternary operator](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-ternary-operator/)

I want to change it to a readable if/else statement but the result gives 500 error.

**The old code (working):**

```
$data = "entityId=" . ($request->payment_option == 'hyperpay_mada' ? env('HYPERPAY_MADA_ENTITY') ? env('HYPERPAY_VISA_ENTITY') : env('HYPERPAY_APPLEPAY_ENTITY') ).
            "&amount=" . str_replace(',','',number_format($order->grand_total,2)) .
            "&currency=SAR" .
            "&billing.city=" .$order->city.
            "&billing.state=" .$order->city.
            "&billing.postcode=0000".
            "&billing.country=SA".
            "&customer.givenName=" .$order->name.
            "&paymentType=DB" .
//            "&testMode=EXTERNAL" .
            "&customer.email=" . (!empty(session('shipping_info')['email']) && session('shipping_info')['email'] != 'null' && session('shipping_info')['email'] != null ? session('shipping_info')['email'] :'shopcustomer'. rand(10000, 99999).'@parduswear.com') .
            "&merchantTransactionId=" . uniqid();
```

**What I am trying to do:**

```
function paymentMethods() {
                if($request->payment_option == 'hyperpay_mada'){
                    env('HYPERPAY_MADA_ENTITY').
                } elseif($request->payment_option == 'hyperpay_visa'){
                    .env('HYPERPAY_VISA_ENTITY').
                } elseif($request->payment_option == 'hyperpay_applepay'){
                    env('HYPERPAY_APPLEPAY_ENTITY').
                }
            }
            
            $data = "entityId=" . paymentMethods() .
            "&amount=" . str_replace(',','',number_format($order->grand_total,2)) .
            "&currency=SAR" .
            "&billing.city=" .$order->city.
            "&billing.state=" .$order->city.
            "&billing.postcode=0000".
            "&billing.country=SA".
            "&customer.givenName=" .$order->name.
            "&paymentType=DB" .
//            "&testMode=EXTERNAL" .
            "&customer.email=" . (!empty(session('shipping_info')['email']) && session('shipping_info')['email'] != 'null' && session('shipping_info')['email'] != null ? session('shipping_info')['email'] :'shopcustomer'. rand(10000, 99999).'@parduswear.com') .
            "&merchantTransactionId=" . uniqid();
```

I tried also adding the if statement without creating a function yet gives me the same 500 error.

Comment: 1. When you call `env(....)`, you should return the value so that the caller can use it: `return env(...);` 2. `$request` is undefined in your function. You need to pass it to the function to be able to use it in it. 3. You need to use `;` at the end of your statements: `return env(....);` instead of `.`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you! it worked, but now Apple pay direct to 404. Weird because the value of the radio input of payment option doesn't seem to have any routing issues. I will keep digging for the error, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this code its worked for me:

```
    $brand = $request->brand ;
    if($brand == 'VISA'){
        $entityID = '8ac7a4c780affe890ffsdfdf0f4b0e29';
    }elseif($brand = 'MASTER'){
        $entityID = '8ac7a4c780aasfsf180b1df0f4b0e29';
    }
    elseif($brand == 'MADA'){
        $entityID = '8ac7a4c780affe890180b1dwreae40e9d';
    }else{
        $entityID = '8ac7a4c780affe890180b1dfdaf600ea1';
    }
    
    $url = "https://eu-test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts";
    $data = "entityId=$entityID" .
                "&amount=$request->amount" .
                "&currency=SAR" .
                "&testMode=INTERNAL".
                "&paymentType=DB";
```